# How could you express the following double integral in term of a single integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How could I express the $$\int\int e^{(x^2+y^2)^2} dA$$ in terms of a single integral with respect to r where D is a disk with center (0,0) and radius 1

Comment: polar coordinates: r²=x²+y² (Don't forget the extra r in front of the differential).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos t\;,\;\;y=r\sin t\;,\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi \implies$$

$$\int\int\limits_D e^{(x^2+y^2)^2}dA=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{2\pi}re^{r^4} dt\,dr=2\pi\int\limits_0^1re^{r^4}dr$$

Comment: Nicely done! +1

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $dxdy\to rdrd\theta$ so you'll have $$2\pi\int_0^1\exp(r^4)rdr$$

Comment: Yes, sir. +1...

Comment: Short and sweet! +1

Comment: How are you today? I'm having a slow day at MSE, but otherwise I'm doing pretty well.

Comment: @amWhy: Like me. I have been sooooo slow  these days also. I am on a local trip nearby.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use polar coordinates. There will be no $\theta$ in the new integrand, so we can integrate with respect to $\theta$ immediately.